# Has J K Rowling ever created any official Harry Potter quizzes/puzzles?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

There are many different Harry Potter trivia puzzles that can be found online, some better than others. Did JKR ever create any herself?

### Are there any official Harry Potter quizzes/puzzles that were made by J K Rowling?

Comment: Does WOMBAT count?

Comment: @Au101 - Yes. Also, self-answer, so feel free to downvote. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fiendishly Difficult Crossword

Appeared in the forth and final issue of *The Daily Prophet*.
Sadly this is not available outside of private collections.
A glimpse of the contents can be [found on the Harry Potter Lexicon](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/item/fiendishly-difficult-crossword/) and in *J.K. Rowling - A Bibliography*.

> [image]
>   **Across**
>   1. She has a backing group of banshees
>   42. The colour of the Quaffle (3)
>   **Down**
>   49. Your worst nightmare as a Bertie Bott bean flavour (3)

### W.O.M.B.A.T. (Wizards’ Ordinary Magic and Basic Aptitude test)

They were three of these (Grade 1 through 3). They were released on JK Rowling's old website for limited times starting on March 31st, 2006. Back when they were online, it was possible to get a grade on them, although the answers were never officially released.

> [image]

The questions (along with commentary by Steve Vander Ark and Belinda Hobbs) can be found [archived on the Harry Potter Lexicon](http://beta.hp-lexicon.org/item/w-o-m-b-a-t-tests/).  Fortunately, a fan back then by the name of Roonwit had systematically taken them multiple times to determine [what all of the correct answers were](http://pastebin.com/raw/wx27jBS2).

### Bonus

- JK Rowling also wrote three personality quizzes for Pottermore: a [Sorting Hat quiz](https://my.pottermore.com/sorting-hat), a [wand quiz](https://my.pottermore.com/wand), and a [Patronus quiz](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/565874507907600385) (which was never released).
- [Scholastic](http://harrypotter.scholastic.com/) and [Bloomsbury](http://www.harrypotter.bloomsbury.com/uk/fun-stuff/harry-potter-trivia-challenge/) have both made online Harry Potter trivia challenges.
- Trivia board games were released by Mattel based on the [first](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5750/harry-potter-and-sorcerers-stone-trivia-game) and [second](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/11635/harry-potter-and-chamber-secrets-trivia-game) books.

Comment: I'd argue that 'colour of a Quaffle: red' hardly counts as "fiendishly difficult"! Interesting, though.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - This *was* the Daily Prophet.